# FInd all the points that lie with in a spherical region

Tags: python, list, search

For example, find the image below, which explains the problem for a simple 2D case. The label (N) and coordinates (x,y) for each point is known. I need to find all the point labels that lie within the red circle

My actual problem is in 3D and the points are  not uniformly distributed

[image]

Sample input file which contain coordinates of 7.25 M points is attached here [point file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1elSabMbRnwVE1TSlNzYUFXeWc/view?usp=sharing).

I tried the following piece of code

```
import numpy as np

C = [50,50,50]

R = 20 

centroid = np.loadtxt('centroid') #chk the file attached

def dist(x,y): return sum([(xi-yi)**2 for xi, yi in zip(x,y)])

elabels=[i+1 for i in range(len(centroid)) if dist(C,centroid[i])<=R**2]
```

For an single search it takes ~ 10 min. Any suggestions to make it faster ?

Thanks,
Prithivi

Comment: Python is a scripting language, which means that every line is converted into machine code every time it's launched. A programming language, like C, Java, Pascal, ..., is first completely compiled before running, going much faster. Therefore I'd advise you to start using a non-scripting programming language.

Answer (score 2):

When using `numpy`, avoid using list comprehensions on arrays.

Your computation can be done using vectorized expressions like this

```
centre = np.array((50., 50., 50.))
points = np.loadtxt('data')

distances2= np.sum((points-centre)**2, axis=1)
```

`points` is a `N x 2` array, `points-centre` is also a `N x 2` array,
`(points-centre)**2` computes the squares of each element of the difference and eventually `np.sum(..., axis=1)` sums the elements of the squared differences along axis no. 1, that is, across columns.

To filter the array of positions, you can use boolean indexing

```
close = points[distances2<max_dist**2]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! its getting done in 0.4 sec. 

Actually I need the indices and not the values, I use

 ind = [i+1 for labels in close for i in range(len(close)) if labels == points[i]]

Is there a better way of doing it ?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do... At any rate a vector of the indexes is the value of the expression `np.arange(N)[distances2<max_dist**2]`

Answer (score 1):

You are heavily calling the `dist` function. You could try to low level optimize it, and control with the timeit Python module which is more efficient. On my machine, I tried this one:

```
def dist(x,y):
    d0 = y[0] -x[0]
    d1 = y[1] -x[1]
    d2 = y[2] -x[2]
    return d0 * d0 + d1*d1 + d2*d2
```

and timeit said it was more than 3 times quicker.

This one was just in the middle:

```
def dist(x,y):
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        d = y[i] - x[i]
        s += d * d
    return s
```